# Spongycastle provider not working on Android

Tags: java, android, security, bouncycastle, spongycastle

I am trying to use Spongy Castle on my Android application. As per these [instructions](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/), I have added the jar files and then called this method to include provider.

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
```

But I still get the error on this line:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("SC");
```

The Exception I get is this:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore SC implementation not found
```

I have spent several hours on this and I cannot figure out what I have missed.

Comment: are you sure the KeyStore is called "SC"?

Comment: "SC" is not a KeyStore rather a provider. It works if I use the default "BKS" provider but not with Spongy Castle provider

Comment: Would it be enough to use "BC"?

Comment: `KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME); //"SC"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Eclipse, I recommended you download **[this example](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle-eclipse)** and compile it. Based on the example, "SC" is not a `KeyStore`.

If you need another example, there is a good tutorial [**here**](http://nelenkov.blogspot.it/2011/12/using-ecdh-on-android.html) (ECDH - Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman on Android).